# jQuery messes with pure CSS animations

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I just started playing with pure CSS animations and I noticed that some animations don't work when jQuery is present. So far I noticed that translate properties like translateY don't work.

I'm providing two jsfiddle examples, one with jQuery and one without it. Everything else is the same. There is no custom JavaScript code, just the inclusion of the jQuery library.

- **Without jQuery** (notice both animations working): http://jsfiddle.net/HsPuV/3/
- **With jQuery** (only red is working): http://jsfiddle.net/HsPuV/4/

CSS code:

```
.floating{
    animation-name: floating;
    -webkit-animation-name: floating;

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(8%);  
    }   
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50%); 
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}
```

If you open the developer tools inspector and deactivate and activate the **-webkit-animation-name** property the animation will start running! I'm testing with Chrome. It's not working at all with Firefox or IE.

**Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?**

**UPDATE**: Apparently it just doesn't work with jQuery 1.9.1 on some systems

**UPDATE**: It works for the edge versions o jQuery, so it's probably a bug that was already solved. For it to work on Firefox, it needs to be prefixed with -moz.

Comment: both work for me... Chrome v30.0.1599.101

Comment: That's weird, I have the same build as you. What OS? I'm running Windows 7. It's also not working on my Android phone.

Comment: Both examples are working fine here too (Safari 7 on OS X 10.9)

Comment: OSX 10.6, Chrome v27.0.1453.116, reported issue is true for me (red only animated with jquery library enabled).

Comment: Windows 7 - Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 reported error is true.

Comment: @fromvega Win7. This is weird... :O

Comment: Not working (only the red moves) Mac OSX Maverics, Chrome 30.0.1599.101

Comment: Both work on Chromium 28.0.1500.71 and Firefox 24.0 on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/HsPuV/6/

Comment: @RobertRozas yeah, it works with previous versions but not with jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: If i change to jquery 2.0.2 it's working too...maybe it's an issue with that specific version(1.9.1)

Comment: If it works for the edge versions then it was probably fixed. I do not see a problem with 1.8.1 though on Chrome 30 Windows, both animations run. Be sure you are running incognito to disable all plugins that may be injecting stuff into the page.

Comment: It works for the edge versions!